# Django: persistent database-backed settings

Tags: python, database, django

I want to have some database stored settings for my Django app - just some key-value pairs. Does Django have a conventional way of doing this / something built in for it, or should I implement it myself?

```
class Setting(models.Model):
     key = models.TextField()
     value = models.TextField()
```

Of course, I'd want to be able to store any data type for keys and values. Perhaps I could use pickle to coerce them all into strings.

Comment: Possibly relevant? http://www.chicagodjango.com/blog/django-settings-database/

Comment: You could make `value` a [JSONField](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/377/) or a [PickleField](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-picklefield/0.1).

Answer (score 0):

I've just been playing with the django-satchmo e-store application. Satchmo uses satchmo-livesettings or just livesettings to achieve this goal. In addition to that it is possible to change the settings using the admin interface.

The only problem is that I didn't find a tutorial on how to use livesettings. But if you browse the satchmo code, you'll see how it works.

Here is my example

```
from livesettings import config_register, StringValue, PositiveIntegerValue
SHOP_GROUP = ConfigurationGroup('SHOP', ('ShirtSale Shop Settings'), ordering=0)
CHARGE_PORTO = config_register(
    BooleanValue(SHOP_GROUP,
             'CHARGE_PORTO',
             description = ('Porto Erheben?'),
             help_text = ("Wird bei Bestellungen zusaetzlich ein Porto erhoben?"),
             default = True))
```

I've included those lines in the config.py file. To execute this file it was necessary to:

```
import config
```

in the admin.py file (I'm wondering whether this is necessary)

In order to access the settings I've included the following to the urls.py file:

```
(r'^settings/', include('livesettings.urls')),
```